# MediaPlayer Reset takes long time

Tags: android, media-player, android-service, android-music-player, background-music

My app is streaming music using `Service` and `MediaPlayer`, but i have a problem when trying to reset the mediaplayer to play next track. resetting mediaplayer takes long time and causes UI to freeze for a while when press next quickly multiple times although I call it in another thread.

Here is my snippet of code which i use to play track from my list

```
private void playTrack(int position) {
    if (!isAudioFocusAvailable())
        return;
    try {
        sendBufferingStarted();
        // Problem is here
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mTracks.get(mCurrentPosition).getUrl());
        mIsBuffering = true;
        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mIsPaused = false;
        acquireWifiWakeLock();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

Any suggestions to avoid resetting and UI freeze problems

Answer (score 0):

try this code it may help

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if(!isPlaying){
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(soundid[position]);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true; // reproducir es true

    }else{

        isPlaying = false;
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(soundid[position]);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;

    }

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
            mPlayer.release();
            isPlaying = false;
        }

    });
}
```